# Lost variable i script

Tags: javascript, php

I have some problem with a variable in my script I need to "send" the variable through some different files

The variable comes from the link:

```
index.php?email=emailname@emailname.com
```

The script is a file upload script. It's using 3 files in the process, please here:

```
/public_html/upload/index.php
/public_html/upload/content/index.php
/public_html/upload/content/UploadHandler.php
```

`/public_html/upload/index.php` is that runs the script and where the variable is received from the link: 
`index.php?email=emailname@emailname.com`

The file code of `/public_html/upload/index.php` looks like:

```
<?php

// change the name below for the folder you want
$dir = "content/".$_GET["email"];

$file_to_write = 'test.txt';
$content_to_write = "The content";

if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
    mkdir($dir);
}

$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

// a different way to write content into
// fwrite($file,"Hello World.");

fwrite($file, $content_to_write);

// closes the file
fclose($file);

// this will show the created file from the created folder on screen
include $dir . '/' . $file_to_write;

$_SESSION['tmem']= $_GET["email"];
?>
```

I know that `$_GET["email"]` works since I can the code: `<?=$_GET["email"]?>` on the `index.php` file to see if it receive the variable.

The code:

```
$_SESSION['tmem']= $_GET["email"];
```

should forward the variable to the next file:

```
/public_html/upload/content/index.php
```

that looks like this:

```
session_start();
$dir = "content/" . $_GET["email"];
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler( array ('upload_url' =>$dir) );
```

And that code should forward the variable to the codes of the script where the upload patch is. Codes on the file: `/public_html/upload/content/UploadHandler.php` looks like:

```
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.$_GET['email'].'/',  
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$_GET['email'].'/',           
'input_stream' => 'php://input',
'user_dirs' => false,
'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
'param_name' => 'files',
```

Can somebody see where in the process I lose the variable?

Comment: What happens when someone does `/index.php?email=../index.php`?

Comment: You have to add `session_start();` to the top of first php file _(/public_html/upload/index.php)_ as well. You also need to use `$_SESSION['tmem']` instead of `$_GET["email"]` in the second and third files _(/public_html/upload/content/index.php), (/public_html/upload/content/UploadHandler.php)_

Answer (score -1):

I think, in this part of code:

```
session_start();
$dir = "content/" . $_GET["email"];
```

you try to get your "email" from URI instead of getting it from session (tmem).

Comment: Please first use the comment section to communicate with the OP and when you were sure about the final answer, then post the answer.

Comment: I would gladly do it this way. Unfortunately I cannot comment original posts until I reach 50 reputation points. And you just didn't help me on this...

Comment: I know and sorry for the down-vote. but posting incomplete answers is not a good way to increase your reputation...